# Combining Polymorphic Associations with Rich Many-to-Many Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, polymorphic-associations

Right now I have a rich many-to-many association with VideoVote as the independent record.

```
class VideoVote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :video
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :video_votes
  has_many :voted_videos,
    :through => :video_votes,
    :source => :video
end

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :video_votes
  has_many :voted_users,
    :through => :video_votes,
    :source => :user
end
```

However, I want to trasform this into a polymorphic association where comments can also have many VideoVotes (I realize this is confusing, so I should probably change it to Votes). (also, a video will have many comments.) How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first want to add `voteable_id:integer` and `voteable_type:string` to your video_votes table.

Then your models will look like:

```
class VideoVote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :voteable, :polymorphic => true


end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :video_votes, :as => :voteable
  #code
end

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :video_votes, :as => :voteable
  #code
end
```

Then you can access them just like any other has_many:

```
@video.video_votes
@comment.video_votes
#etc.
```

Comment: for clarity i think it's votes that belong to various things like comments and videos.

Comment: ok, but how does this combine with the `has_many :through` associations? I want for a video to have the users who voted on it through the votes, as well as for users to have the videos they voted on through votes. I also want comments to have the users who voted on it though votes, as well as users to have the comments they voted through votes.

Comment: You would do the same idea with :through, but now you would do  :foreign_key => "voteable_id"(instead of source), for your has_many relationships.

Comment: `class User < ActiveRecord::Base`
  `has_many :video_votes`
  `has_many :voted_videos,`
    `:through => :video_votes,`
    `:foreign_key => "voteable_id"`